# Show file in folder Android java

Tags: android, file, android-activity, parent

I have a program that lists some files from the android file system. I have implemented a dialog when a file is long clicked , and the dialog has the option to show the file in its parent folder like in windows `show in explorer`. I don't know how to use the path of that file to start an Intent for viewing the folder in which that file is located please help. Here is what i got so far...

```
 private void options(final File path){

        AlertDialog.Builder mybuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mybuilder.setTitle(R.string.title);
        mybuilder.setCancelable(false);
        mybuilder.setItems(new String[]{"Show in Parent", "Delete", "Open"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               //Implement a switch on these choices
                File r=path;Uri m=Uri.fromFile(path);
                switch(which){
                    case 0:
                        //To be changed so that the an activity to show the
                         parent folder of File path is started via an intent or whichever means*/
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //delete file
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //open
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

This method handles[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu5II.jpg) the dialog item onclick listener, i just desire to have the file shown in its parent folder via the application that android system understands to be the default one, Thanks

Comment: So you want to open a file browser/explorer that initially shows the content of the directory of the file?

Comment: Precisely, that is what i intend to achieve

Comment: There are no default apps on Android devices that show the content of folders using a classic file parh.

Comment: Okay, looks like am outta luck

Comment: I have a samsung android phone and the program samsung made for managing files has a context menu command for showing the parent folder of file

Comment: I dont understand. If you see a file in a file explorer then the explorer shows already the contents of the parent folder. But yes a file explorer can show files in folders but now you should tell that app to start up in an indicated folder. Quite something different. What is it that you wanna say?

Comment: No the file manager has a search utility, some sort of a searchview, when you long click a file after search results show up, a context menu shows up then you choose the show in parent folder, it will show the file in folder

Comment: So you are not browsing but searching. Ok. I must admit that i never searched for a file on an Android device. Of course the explorer can show all files in the parent directory.  But that is something different from letting it start with a specified folder. I used to install ES File Explorer and OI Explorer and others. They would open in the specified folder if started with ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Can you help me do that with ACTION_VIEW please?

Comment: Please try first and put the code in your post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749593/mime-type-for-directories-in-android